# Chipmunk 6 space initialization

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am trying to use [chipmunk6.x](https://chipmunk-physics.net/) and having problems with it. It is not creating the physics environment. How do I enable the chipmunk6.x physics environment in my project? The space manager system is working well. I hope there is no problem with the chipmunk lib attachment. 
I am using the cocos2d old version I just replaced the chipmunk lib.

```
space = cpSpaceNew();

space->gravity = cpv(0, -100);

//
// rogue shapes
// We have to free them manually
//
// bottom
cpShape *walls_[4];
walls_[0] = cpSegmentShapeNew( space->staticBody, cpv(0,0), cpv(s.width,0), 0.0f);

// top
walls_[1] = cpSegmentShapeNew( space->staticBody, cpv(0,s.height), cpv(s.width,s.height), 0.0f);

// left
walls_[2] = cpSegmentShapeNew( space->staticBody, cpv(0,0), cpv(0,s.height), 0.0f);

// right
walls_[3] = cpSegmentShapeNew( space->staticBody, cpv(s.width,0), cpv(s.width,s.height), 0.0f);

for( int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    walls_[i]->e = 1.0f;
    walls_[i]->u = 1.0f;
    cpSpaceAddStaticShape(space, walls_[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific than "It is not creating the physics environment."

The code you pasted otherwise looks fine. What happens with it, and what are you expecting should happen.

Comment: I am regularly creating a body and attaching it with the shape and expecting to attach it withe the shape. I hope it will show the gravity effect but it is not. that is it is not creating the environment or can say it is not enabling the chipmunk.